# Text message vs iMessage on iPhones

Tags: iphone, messages

iMessage boxes are blue, but I noticed at certain times when I text other iPhone owners the messages are green and show as text messages therefore unable to show the read stamp.  I understand that this can happen when there's not I messaging available for whatever reason that  I'm not too sure about but does this also happen when someone blocks a person?

Answer (score 2):

**No**: [blocking will actually generally result in your phone sending as an iMessage that doesn't get delivered.](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-tell-if-someone-has-blocked-your-phone-number-ios-8-ios-9-3475883/) [Any number of things](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/fix-ios-imessage-problems-bug-messages-not-delivered-3470405/) could still be happening to send as text. You or the other person may have sending/receiving as SMS enabled or iMessage disabled. You or the other person may not have a proper internet connection for a number of reasons. [iMessage servers may be down](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/)–which, although incredibly rare and usually noticeable, has happened on a few occasions when AWS servers are down or other problems occur.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. It seems deliberate from someone. Does it happen when "do not disturb" is set?

Comment: @KatS. It shouldn't.